# Insert data to database - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This creates a new project for me. However, what i want to do is to add the additional fields in the database which belong to another database table called projects_air AND to add those air details on for that project .

```
  public function newProject(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $attributes = [];
        $attributes['title'] = $data['title'];
        $attributes['start_date'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($data['start_date']));
        $attributes['end_date'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($data['end_date']));
        $attributes['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
        $attributes['description'] = $data['description'];
        $attributes['air'] = '10';
        $attributes['water'] = '19';
        $attributes['lat'] = $data['lat'];
        $attributes['lng'] = $data['lng'];



//        var_dump($attributes);
//        return;

        $project = Projects::create($attributes);
        $air = Projects_air::create($airattributes);

        if($project)
            return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Project added successfully');

        var_dump($data);
        return;
    }
```

ADDITIONAL DATA TO INSERT TO DATABASE:

```
     $airattributes['dust'] = $data['dust'];
    $airattributes['noise'] = $data['noise'];
    $airattributes['temperature'] = $data['temperature'];
    $airattributes['radiation'] = $data['radiation'];
```

I want that these data also belong to a project they both(projects table and projects_air table) have a column called "project_id"

I HAVE TRIED USING THIS `$air = $project->air()->create($airattributes);` BUT IM GETTING AN ERROR THAT COLUMN PROJECTS_ID DOES NOT EXIST WHICH IS TRUE. IT SHOULD BE PROJECT_ID BUT I DONT KNOW WHERE THE ERROR IS

here you can view the interface: http://188.166.166.143/projects/add

UPDATE:
Air Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Air extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'projects_air';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'project_id', 'temperature', 'radiation', 'dust', 'noise'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id',
    ];
}
```

PROJECTS CONTROLLER

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Projects;
use App\Enroll;
use View;
use Auth;
use App\Air;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Projects $projects)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->projects = $projects;
    }

    // Add new project
    public function addProject()
    {
        return View::make('projects/add_project');
    }


    // Process new project
    public function newProject(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $attributes = [];
        $attributes['title'] = $data['title'];
        $attributes['start_date'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($data['start_date']));
        $attributes['end_date'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($data['end_date']));
        $attributes['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
        $attributes['description'] = $data['description'];
        $attributes['air'] = '10';
        $attributes['water'] = '19';
        $attributes['lat'] = $data['lat'];
        $attributes['lng'] = $data['lng'];
        $airattributes['dust'] = $data['dust'];
        $airattributes['noise'] = $data['noise'];
        $airattributes['temperature'] = $data['temperature'];
        $airattributes['radiation'] = $data['radiation'];
        $airattributes['project_id'] = $data['project_id'];


//        var_dump($attributes);
//        return;

        $project = Projects::create($attributes);
        $air = $project->air()->create($airattributes);

        var_dump($air);
        return;


        if($project)
            return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Project added successfully');

        var_dump($data);
        return;
    }

    // Show all projects
    public function showProjects()
    {

        $data = Projects::get();
        return View::make('projects/list_projects')->with('projects', $data);

    }

    // Show single project
    public function showSingleProject($id)
    {
        if(is_null($id))
            return back()->with('error', 'Invalid project');


        $project = Projects::where('id', $id)->first();

        if(is_null($project))
            return back()->with('error', 'Project not found');


        return View::make('projects/single_project2')->with('project', $project);

    }

    // Show single project
    public function showEditProject($id)
    {
        if(is_null($id))
            return back()->with('error', 'Invalid project');


        $project = Projects::where('id', $id)->first();

        if(is_null($project))
            return back()->with('error', 'Project not found');


        $hasAccess = 0;


        if(!empty($project->enrolls))
        {
            foreach($project->enrolls as $enroll)
            {

                if($enroll->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
                {
                    $hasAccess = 1;
                    break;
                }


            }
        }


        if($project->created_by == Auth::user()->id)
            $hasAccess = 1;



        if($hasAccess != 1)
            return back()->with('error', 'You are not allowed to edit this project');


        return View::make('projects/edit_project')->with('project', $project);

    }




    // Show single project
    public function showDeleteProject($id)
    {
        if(is_null($id))
            return back()->with('error', 'Invalid project');


        $project = Projects::where('id', $id)->first();

        if(is_null($project))
            return back()->with('error', 'Project not found');


        if($project->created_by != Auth::user()->id)
            return back()->with('error', 'You are not the owner of this project');


        return View::make('projects/delete_project')->with('project', $project);

    }


    public function processDeleteProject(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        if(!is_null($data['pk']))
            Projects::where('id', $data['pk'])->delete();


        return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Project deleted successfully');

    }

    public function enrollToProject($id)
    {
        if(is_null($id))
            return back()->with('error', 'Invalid project');

        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $attributes = [];
        $attributes['user_id'] = $userId;
        $attributes['project_id'] = $id;

        $enrolled = Enroll::create($attributes);

        if($enrolled)
            return back()->with('success', 'You have successfully enrolled to this project');

    }


    public function showImportView()
    {

        return View::make('projects/import_project');
    }



    public function processImport(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->all();

        if($data['file'])
        {
            $csvData = file_get_contents($data['file']);
            $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
            $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $lines);
            $csv = array_shift($csv);

            if(is_null($csv))
                return back()->with('error', 'Its Empty');



            $attributes = [];
            $attributes['title'] = $csv[0];
            $attributes['start_date'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($csv[1]));
            $attributes['end_date'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($csv[2]));
            $attributes['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
            $attributes['description'] = $csv[3];
            $attributes['air'] = $csv[4];
            $attributes['water'] = $csv[5];


            $project = Projects::create($attributes);

            if($project)
                return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Project imported successfully');

//            var_dump($attributes);
//            echo '<pre />';
//            return;
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: So where're you creating the array in your code above? You should create `airattributes` and ensure you have the proper `fillable` attribute in the projects_air model

Comment: Can you add your model code? I'm afraid I'm not following exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the relations in your model:

```
class Projects extends Model {
    public function air() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Projects_air');
    }
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
$project = Projects::create($attributes);
$air = $project->air()->create($airattributes);
```

Comment: where should i define the $air ?

Comment: you don't need to define it, you will assign to it the new created air project

Comment: they both have different tables: air has different table and project has different table.

Comment: I have edited your code, you need to use `air()` instead of `air`. Relationships should be accessed as a method if you wish to access the relationship Query builder, which in this instance, you do.